# Whitelist all subdomains VBA macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I have implemented a macro to append a string before any hyperlinks in an outlook email. however, I put a domain whitelist which is working fine for example if I whitelist https : //google.com then it will whitelist it in addition to https : //google.com/etc.. and anything that follows it.

My problem is if someone wants to visit https://mail.google.com or any other subdomain it will not work and will append it to be APPEND_THIS_https://mail.google.com. How can I allow all subdomains to be in the whitelist?

```
Dim myStr As String
    Dim myURL As String
    ' Declare whitlist URL variables
    'Dim whiteURL01 As String
    'Dim whiteURL02 as string

    myURL = "APPEND_THIS_"
    ' Add URLs to whitelist here
    whiteURL01 = "https://google.com"

    ' Store the HTML Bodyin a variable
    myStr = Msg.htmlbody
    ' Update all URLs
    myStr = Replace(myStr, "href=""", "a href=" & myURL, , , vbTextCompare)

    ' Process whitelist
    myStr = Replace(myStr, myURL & whiteURL01, whiteURL01, , , vbTextCompare)

    ' Assign back to HTML Body
    Msg.htmlbody = myStr
    ' Save the mail
    Msg.Save
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. I added an extra loop to look thru the entire message body in case there are several loops.

```
Dim myStr As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim white_url_found As Boolean

myStr=Msg.HTMLBody
myURL = "APPEND_THIS_"

Dim whiteURL(0 To 2) As String

whiteURL(0) = ".google.com"
whiteURL(1) = ".facebook.com"
whiteURL(2) = "mailto:"

searchstart = InStr(1, myStr, "href=")
While searchstart <> 0
    nextstart = InStr(searchstart + 1, myStr, "href=")
    white_url_found = False
    For i = LBound(whiteURL()) To UBound(whiteURL())
        URL_pos = InStr(searchstart, myStr, whiteURL(i))
        If URL_pos > 0 And (URL_pos < nextstart Or nextstart = 0) Then
            white_url_found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If Not white_url_found Then
        myStr = Left(myStr, searchstart - 1) & Replace(myStr, "href=" & Chr(34), "href=" & Chr(34) & myURL, searchstart, 1, vbTextCompare)
        If nextstart <> 0 Then nextstart = nextstart + Len(myURL)
    End If

    searchstart = nextstart
Wend
Msg.HTMLBody = myStr
Msg.Save
```

Comment: Great!!! Exactly what i was looking for! It works as needed 2 things though. 1- how do I stop it from appending mailto links 2- I tried mailgoogle.com and it didn't append it. I want it to not append either google.com or xxx.google.com so other fake domains dont pass by. Thank you again!

Comment: also it alaways appends a " prior to the href for example APPEND_THIS_"http://...etc

Comment: Great that it worked. For your first comment, just change the domain in the whitelist to ".google.com". (Add the dot before).

Comment: The "a" was how I read your code that you wanted it to perform, I have edited the code above.

Comment: About mailto links. Why not put "mailto:" in the whitelist.

Comment: Mmm. now it does append everything with the new code :( and still adds a quotation mark (") after the appended text not an "a"

Comment: I got lost in the comments :-) What are the remaining issues?

Comment: the second code you edited doesn't work well as it appends all links and ignores the whitelist. So I went back to use your old code, however, the only issue with your first code is when it appends it adds a quotation mark (") like this APPEND_THIS_"http://...etc but i want it without it :) i couldn't figure out from where it came in the code. otherwise its perfect!

Comment: I think It had something like "href=""" in the replace. Try fiddling with that.

Comment: now it's missing a (/) in addition to the (") with the last edited code like this http://eg.sa/uploads/bug.PNG

Comment: Making it worse... I'll fix it in a couple of hours.

Comment: I think I see the problem. Just to confirm this is what you want, an HTML link would be `<a href="http://www.badlink.com">good link</a>` and you want it to be `<a href="APPEND_THIS_http://www.badlink.com">good link</a>`. Correct?

Comment: I've added Char(34) above to keep the " in the correct place.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik but now the email comes blank. but yes what you mentioned above is what I need :)

Comment: oops. I removed ´myStr=Msg.HTMLBody`

Comment: Ok now it came. However the link looks like that APPEND_THIS_http/www.badlink.com

Anyway, I used your first code and added the char34 change to it and it worked like a charm! but I'm not sure if it's optimized enough since you remove some lines from latter edits? THANK YOU SO MUCH!